# Stream MP3 file MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html, filestreamresult

I am trying to stream a file using the audio HTML5 tag.  I have put the Controller action to return a FileStream and attached it to the src for the audio.  However, the content is not loading into the audio tag and doesn't play when I press the default play button.  I know the controller is working when I access the src directly.  However, it doesn't work in the HTML5 audio tag.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not return a `FileStream`, you should return a `FileStreamResult` or a `FilePathResult` from your controller action, like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult MyAudio()
    {
        var file = Server.MapPath("~/app_data/test.mp3");
        return File(file, "audio/mp3");
    }
}
```

and the `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sound Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <article class="audio">
        <header>
            <h2>Some audio</h2>
        </header>

        <audio controls>
            <source src="@Url.Action("myaudio")" type="audio/mp3" />
            <p>Your browser does not support HTML 5 audio element</p>
        </audio>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't returning file just cause the browser to download the file in full and then begin playing it? Rather then streaming it?